# SQL Error Entity Framework Code First Approach

Tags: entity-framework

I am having troubles connecting to SQL database in code first approach. Details are as below

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="MydbConn"
connectionString="Data Source=hostname\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Test1;UserID=****;Password=****;Integrated Security=True"
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

Below is the Context Helper

```
public class DBContext:DbContext
    {
        public DBContext():base("MydbConn")
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<DBContext>(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<DBContext>());
        }
        public DbSet<User> User { get; set; }
    }
```

The User Model

```
public partial class UserChatLog
    {
        [Key]
        public long UserLogId { get; set; }
        public string EnterpriseId { get; set; }
    }
```

And Finally DBHelper file

```
public void Save(User user)
        {
            DBContext context = new DBContext();
            context.User.Add(User);
            context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
```

I am getting the below exception

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred. The specified LocalDB instance does not exist.
```

Comment: double check your connection string

Comment: SQL Express requires the file to be local. Are you trying to use localdb, or a full instance of SQL?

Comment: I tried everything with the connection string. Could you please help me identify the issue

Comment: I am trying to create Database based on my context on my local SQL 2014 server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your connection string is fine,
this might be the problem.
I think your base constructor is taking `("MydbConn")` as database name
For specifying connection string in the base constructor i believe this is the right way `base("name=MydbConn")`